# Method that resizes images(bitmap, jpeg, png, etc.)

Tags: c#, image

I need a method that resizes an any kind of image like bitmap, jpeg, png. Maybe something like this: `private void imageResize(Image img, int newHeight, int newWidth)` That returns img? What ever works and I am able to call the method somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

Under 'Resizing'